# Best way to print a binary-tree in one line?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, binary-tree

Exemple:
My tree have this elements: 123,234,345,456
My metod is printing this:

```
123 
234
345
456
```

I want this `123 234 345 456`
My code below:

```
def walk(self,x):
    if x!=None:
        self.walk(x.getLeft())
        print(x.getData())
        self.walk(x.getRight())
```

I find a way:

```
 def __init__(self,s=None):
    self._root=None
    self._s=''

  def getS(self):
    return self._s

  def setS(self,s):
    self._s=s

  def walk(self,x):
    if x!=None:
        self.walk(x.getLeft())
        if self.getS()=="":
            s=str(x.getData())
            self.setS(str(self.getS())+s)
        else:
            s=" "+str(x.getData())
            self.setS(str(self.getS())+s)
        self.walk(x.getRight())
```

And just print:

```
 print(t.getS())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add end="" in your print()

```
def walk(self,x):
    if x!=None:
        self.walk(x.getLeft())
        print(x.getData(), end="")
        self.walk(x.getRight())
```

Comment: Thank you man, but this metod is pretty slow to big trees. I added a pretty fast metod :)